# Plot two discrete points in 3-D space

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I plot these two 3-D points in Matlab?

```
P=[0.8061302526383115, 0.8122242071197412, 0.7836563734015345]
```

and

```
Q=[0.80612997, 0.81221923, 0.78366043]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html

You can do:

```
scatter3([P(1),Q(2)],[P(2),Q(2)],[P(3),Q(3)])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll do!